# How to debug the error "X is unsubscriptable"?

Tags: python

I am trying to create a list of the letters in the alphabet and check a user input to see if each character is in the list associated. However, when I try to go through the list to find if the character is in it, it returns with a "Type Error: Value "ASCIIUPPER.index" is unsubscriptable" or Type Error: Value "ASCIILOWER.index" is unsubscriptable.

Here's where I create the list:

```
    import string
    ASCIIUPPER = list(string.ascii_uppercase)
    ASCIILOWER = list(string.ascii_uppercase)
```

and here is where I try to check input:

```
    for count in range(len(userInput1)):
        loc1 = userInput.index[count]
        if loc1 in ASCIIUPPER:
            for count1 in range(26):
                loc2 = ASCIIUPPER.index[count1]
                if loc1 == loc2:
                    finalInput += loc1
                print(finalInput)
```

This is only the first part to the conversion.

Comment: `.index()` is a function call that returns the index of an element in the list, you would use `()` to call it not `[]` (first case). In the second case you already have an index so you would just index into the list with `ASCIIUPPER[count1]`.

Comment: Actually looking close, I'm very confused as to what you are trying to do.

Comment: It's not `ASCIIUPPER` that's unsubscriptable, it's `ASCIIUPPER.index` which is a *function*.

Answer (score 1):

You are using list.index incorrectly. `ASCIIUPPER` is a list right and to get the index of an item in the list use list.index().

`ASCIIUPPER.index('A')` will return 0.

I'm not sure what you are trying to do with the multiple for loops.

If all you want to do is check if user input is a letter isn't this sufficient

```
for loc1 in userInput1:
    if (loc1 in ASCIIUPPER) or (loc1 in ASCIILOWER):
        print loc1
```

Comment: Thank you for the input. Yes all I want to do is check if what they type is in the list, and return the location of that character in the list. So say the input is "Hello" it would take the first letter "H" and see if it is in either of those lists making sure that it is a letter. Then once it confirms it is in that list, It should return a 7" Thanks for the help!